# Unable to mount volume - operation not supported

Tags: mount

I've just installed Ubuntu to my USB drive and the GUI comes up beautifully.

But if I click on any of my devices I get the error:

```
Unable to mount xxxx Volume
Adding read ACL for uid 999 to '/media/ubuntu' failed: Operation not supported
```

Comment: What command are you using/could you post a screenshot/link to?

Comment: I'm not using a command - I'm just at the Ubuntu GUI, click the Home Folder icon, and in the window which opens up, in the top left hand corner there's a list of devices. One of them is "253 GB Volume" (I assume that's my whole hard disk), another is "casper-rw". I click on any of them and the message above comes up.